# Division producing only integers C++

Tags: c++, function, random

I use rand function to generate two random numbers, numerator and denominator, that are used in division, sometimes the result is float and sometimes is integer. How can I generate only an integer result ? here is my code :

```
  srand(time(NULL)); 

integer1 = ((rand() % ( 81 - 5 ) + 5 )*2);
integer2 = ((rand()%3 + 1)*2); 
answer = integer1/integer2;

do {
    cout << "How much is " << integer1 << " divided by " << integer2 << " ? : " << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == integer1/integer2) {
        cout << "Very Good !"<< endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Your answer is false, please try again !"<<endl;
    }

} while ((integer1/integer2!=answer));
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: How are `integer1`, `integer2`, and `answer` declared?

Comment: int integer1, integer2, answer = 0;

Comment: Then how come you can confidently state "sometimes the result is float"? How did you know that?

Comment: Because I've tried it

Comment: And what, specifically, did you see that led to your claim that "sometimes the result is float"?

Comment: Kaabii, we're trying to help.  Based on the program and the fact that `integer1`, `integer2`, and `answer` are all declared as integers, we expect that `answer` will be an integer result.  This is what you want, correct?  Are you sure the code you posted in the current version you are running?

Answer (score 0):

If both operands of `/` are integral types, the result will be integral. If either operand is a floating point type the result will be a floating point type. If you want it to be a truncated integer you'll need to cast to the type you desire.

Comment: Can you please more clarify, using the code snippet I provided ?